# net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error while using fetch API to make request to metaweather API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ssl, ssl-certificate, fetch

I'm making a GET request to metaweather.com API and getting this error in console:
GET https://metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=w net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

And when I paste this URL to my browser it says that connection is insecure with same error code.

How do I fix this?

Code is something like that, nothing special:

```
fetch(query)
    .then(function(response) {console.log(2)})
    .catch(() => {console.log(3)});
```

Comment: Use a different weather API... There is no shortage...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the access is expected at `www.metaweather.com` and not simply `metaweather.com`. While the first provides a correct certificate which matches the name in the URL the last does not. It instead returns a certificate for `redirect.pointhq.com`.